# How to track Firefox beta via a PPA, but not Thunderbird daily builds etc?

Tags: ppa, pinning, firefox

I would like to install the beta of Firefox 4 in lucid or maverick.  I know I can install the ubuntu-mozilla-daily PPA (`ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa`) and have easy apt-get access to firefox-4.0.  However, this repository contains not only Firefox, but also daily builds of Thunderbird and other mozilla products.

If I leave this PPA enabled, `apt-get upgrade` also upgrades Thunderbird 3 to the latest "shredder".  I'm not interested in running a daily build of Thunderbird -- I just want Firefox 4.

Is there some combination of pinning, backporting, or something like that which would make it easy for me to run an up-to-date daily of Firefox 4, but only Firefox 4?

Comment: Re "*What's the best way to install just one package from a PPA that has many packages?*", see [apt - How do I cherry pick packages from a PPA? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170235/how-do-i-cherry-pick-packages-from-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the beta, I suggest ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next which has the latest beta, but not the latest nightly.

If you want the latest nightly, you could set up a cron job that pulls the latest nightly from nightly.mozilla.org and installs it in /usr/local.  I can try to help if you need help.

Just my suggestions.  (I've been using the firefox-next ppa for a while now.)

Comment: Good to know: I'll check out ppa:firefox/firefox-next.  But I'd also be like to know the general case of how to pick just one package from a PPA.

Comment: PS: It's ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next.

Comment: Oops.  :)  I fixed it now.

Comment: I like zpletan's suggestion the best, but after researching this the answer seems to be: you can't. A PPA comes with everything in it or nothing.

Comment: @cha what about these instructions? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Pinning_the_ubuntu-mozilla-daily_PPA

Comment: Thanks, @akaihola -- that looks like exactly the thing.  I didn't know pins could reduce priority for a whole repository.