# Limit which packages can be installed through a PPA

Tags: package-management, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I cherry pick packages from a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170235/how-do-i-cherry-pick-packages-from-a-ppa)

Is it possible to add a PPA but limit what can be installed through it.

Let us say there's a PPA with two packages and I'm interested in one package but not the other. Is it possible to add the repository while telling apt to ignore the second package?