# Security implications of other repos

Tags: midi, add-apt-repository, vst

**Main Question:**

At which point can I trust external, unofficial repos? Are there security implications for blindingly adding third party repos to a workstation?  However, I've been *very suspect* of including non-offical repos.

**Background and my particular case:**

I'd like to install a [Juce](https://launchpad.net/~fabian+roli/+archive/ubuntu/juce). From what I understand, this is a stand alone utility to host VST (virtual instruments used in music production). I've found what appears to be it's [source on github](https://github.com/kunitoki/juced) and have tried to compile that in a throw away VM. However, after receiving an errors on install (to which I may open a ticket here or on github later), I was curious to see if anyone had packaged it for Ubuntu.

Comment: This particular package is apparently being added to [xenials applicaitons](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=juce).  I am assuming the launchpad versions for earlier releases are OK.

Comment: Xenial is the codename for Ubuntu 16.04, out in April.

Comment: So this may be a non-issue in a month then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- **Any repo can overwrite any package by default**. You can [pin a repo to only allow certain packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170235/how-do-i-cherry-pick-packages-from-a-ppa) but that doesn't help against this because...
- Those **packages can write files anywhere**. They'd have to not overwrite any existing  files but there are plenty of places you could hide a malicious file, which isn't to mention...
- **Packages can run anything as root** on install and removal.

So yes, if you can't trust the controller of a repository (or trust that they're vetting the code that's going into the repo), you shouldn't be using that repo. A malicious package is game over.

Comment: As I thought. I generally *do not* add 3rd party repos, but for the particular situation, since Juce should be in 16.04, I should just wait a month. Upvote and many thanks.