# How to install Meld 3 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, gtk, meld

I'm just trying to install [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) 3.x. It has some dependencies and one of them is GTK+ >= 3.14. I am fed up of not able to update to GTK+ 3.14.

I want to know how to install meld latest version which is supported by GTK+ 3.12.

Is there a straight-forward way to install GTK+ 3.12 or Meld on my Ubuntu PC? Please include a step by step process.

PS: I did try installing Meld using Aptitude and Software center. It installs outdated versions. I need the latest version.

Comment: I doubt it. Even the [GNOME3 PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+index?field.series_filter=trusty&batch=75&memo=75&start=75) don't have anything above 3.12 for 14.04

Comment: Is there any reason to not upgrade Ubuntu to the version 16.04? Then you’ll get [libgtk-3-0 version 3.18.9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgtk-3-0) which should allow you to build the most recent Meld yourself.

Comment: Ok I think I'll just edit the question for 3.12 compatible meld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PPA which includes Meld 3.18 for Ubuntu 14.04: [`~jonathonf/backports`](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=trusty). However, it also includes backports of a large number of other packages. I haven't tested this PPA, so maybe you should only install `meld` from it (see [How do I cherry pick packages from a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/170235/158442)) and see if it works.

There's also another PPA which has Meld 3.14: [`~pachulo/meld-backports`](https://launchpad.net/~pachulo/+archive/ubuntu/meld-backports).